# Join tables with most recent observations, SQl server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Edit after comments: I have two tables with date, borrower_id, loan_id as common variables and the combination of the three is an unique key. I want to have only the most recent entry per loan_id in the table1 and matching with the information for same poolcutoffdate (which should be the most recent), same borrower_id and same loan_id. Basically the result should be like a left outer join (table1 is the left).

TABLE 1

```
|poolcutoffdate |   borrower_id |   loan_id |payed_amount   |       
|   2014-06-01  |   subject 1   |   1       |   30          |       
|   2014-08-01  |   subject 1   |   1       |   40          |       
|   2016-06-01  |   subject 1   |   1       |   50          |       
|   2017-06-01  |   subject 1   |   1       |   60          |       
|   2015        |   subject 2   |   5       |   200         |       
|   2016        |   subject 2   |   5       |   220         |       
|   2016        |   subject 2   |   6       |   10          |
```

TABLE 2

```
|poolcutoffdate |   borrower_id |loan_id    |delinquency_days|
|   2014-06-01  |   subject 1   |   1       |   0            |      
|   2014-08-01  |   subject 1   |   1       |   0            |      
|   2016-06-01  |   subject 1   |   1       |   0            |      
|   2017-06-01  |   subject 1   |   1       |   0            |      
|   2015        |   subject 2   |   5       |   0            |      
|   2016        |   subject 2   |   5       |   5            |      
|   2016        |   subject 2   |   6       |   5            |      
|   2018        |   subject 8   |   001     |   0
```

final results

```
|poolcutoffdate |   borrower_id |   loan_id |payed_amount |delinquency_days|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2017-06-01  |   subject 1   |   1       |   60        | 0              |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   2016        |   subject 2   |   5       |   220       | 5              |
----------------------------------------------------- 
|   2016        |   subject 2   |   6       |   10        | 5              |
```

Is there an efficient and complete way to reach the result I need with an unique code? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your sample query only references on e table.  But your question references two.

Comment: Yes thanks, My initial idea was to run two different query to have the most recent observation for the two table, download the data and then do the merge in stata. But I want to do it all in SQL if possible.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please edit the tags accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio

Comment: What does "a merge" mean? What do you mean exactly by "a join"? Are your "final result" what you get or what you want to get? Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes a clear explanation of what the output is supposed to look like in terms of the input. Don't expect us to guess from an example. (But give one.) Use enough words & sentences & references to examples to say what you mean. PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work, where `t1` and `t2` are your two respective tables:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.delinquency_days
FROM t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Poolcutoffdate) AS most_recent,
                           borrower_id,
                           loan_id
                    FROM t1
                    GROUP BY borrower_id, loan_id) a ON t1.Poolcutoffdate = a.most_recent
                                                        AND t1.borrower_id = a.borrower_id
                                                        AND t1.loan_id = a.loan_id
        LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.Poolcutoffdate = a.most_recent
                        AND t2.borrower_id = a.borrower_id
                        AND t2.loan_id = a.loan_id
```

...BUT, the situation would be greatly aided by having unique id's on each record - so as to make the join criteria a little simpler! In other words, in my answer I am assuming that the `Poolcutoffdate`/`borrower_id`/`loan_id` combination is a unique one.

Comment: If you are looking for specific borrowers and loans, there are a couple of ways to narrow down the results. One is to put a `WHERE` clause in the inner query; another is to put a `WHERE` clause in the outer query. Doing it the first way could speed the whole operation up if you have a very large number of records.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Your approach seems promising. Unfortunatly the only unique identifier is the identifier of the loan, that cannot be repeated more than once in the same poolcutoffdate. So maybe I should create a concatenation between the two in order to have an unique key. Of course in the practice I have to ask again how this could be done, but thanks again.

Comment: And yes the combination between the three needs to be unique. But of course those are values provided by banks so in practice who knows. But I am interested only in the unique combination, yes

Comment: It's okay that you don't have a unique identifier. The answer that I'm giving you should work as is (you just have to replace my table names with yours). It would just lead to a less verbose query (and be good database practice) to have an identifier of some sort on each row. At the same time, I'm no stranger to situations where the data comes from another source without ideal structuring.

Comment: Unfortunatly running the query the result is: Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Express? It has some restrictions in regard to memory usage. You might need to set your database to grow with the amount of storage it needs. Have a look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46643/could-not-allocate-a-new-page-for-database-because-of-insufficient-disk-space).

Answer (score 0):

You can just join the tables and then get the most recent result:

```
select t1.Poolcutoffdate, t1.borrower_id, t1.loan_id, t1.payed_amount, t2.delinquency_days
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.loan_id = t2.loan_id and t1.year = t2.year  -- not sure if subject is needed
where t1.year = (select max(tt1.year) from table1 tt1 where t1.loan_id = t1.loan_id);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful answer. Unfortunatly I do not want the most recent observation over all, but the most recent observation for the identifier loan_id (taking into consideration that the same borrower could have different loans but there is an unique id for the combination between poolcutoffdate borrower_id and loan_id)

Comment: Maybe I need a simple GROUP BY statement

Comment: @A_Bed . . . Did you run this query?  It returns the most recent year per loan.